# How to query model instances outside of the current object

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have the following models:

```
class PermanentList(models.Model):
      permanent_employees = models.ManyToManyField(Employee, through='PermanentMembership')

class EventList(models.Model):
      event_employees = models.ManyToManyField(Employee, through='EventMembership')

class Employees(models.Model):
      email = models.EmailField()
```

And the following through models to handle the M2M relationship:

```
class PermanentMembership(models.Model):
      permanent_list = models.ForeignKey(PermanentList, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
      permanent_employees = models.ForeignKey(Employee,null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

      class Meta:
           constraints = [models.UniqueConstraint(
                               fields=['permanent_list', 'permanent_employees'],
                               name="unique_event_list_employees")]

class EventMembership(models.Model):
      event_list = models.ForeignKey(EventList, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
      event_employees = models.ForeignKey(Employee,null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

      def clean(self):
           // missing code

      class Meta:
           constraints = [models.UniqueConstraint(
                              fields=['event_list', 'event_employees'],
                              name="unique_event_list_employees")]
```

> EDITS:
>
> - Each `Employee` can only be in 1 `EventList` or 1 `PermanentList`
> - `EventList` and `PermanentList` are completely separate models, only sharing `Employees`. They can't be combined and managed as one
>     list.

2 Questions:

1. How can I validate each `event_employee` using `def clean(self):` to ensure that if an `Employee` is already on a `PermanentList` they can not be added to a `EventList`?
2. If an `Employee` is already on an `EventList` how can I create a function to transfer them to a `PermanentList`? Can this be done on a `Model` class or would it have to be in a `View`? How would I go about this?

Comment: Each employee can only be in 1 `EventList` or 1 `PermanentList`?

Comment: How are `PermanentList` and `EventList` related?  It looks like this should be combined into one `MembershipList` model that has column that declares what type of membership it is.

Comment: @IainShelvington Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica that would work except in practice they have several hundred fields that differ from each other, so it would be a nightmare. Is there a way to manage it with conditional logic that you can think of?

Comment: @alias51 we're missing 1 model here I think? Is there a Job/Event model to which all these employees are getting assigned to? Just to confirm: each employee is assigned to 1 Job/Event but is either a perm or temp?

Comment: @IainShelvington. Apologies if I have not been clear, but no these are all the models. `Employees` are either on a Permanent or Event List (the app doesn't go further than that). As ReinstateMonica says, usually you could just have a column on a single Membership list but there are actually lots of different fields unique to `EventList` or `PermanentList` that would prevent this. 

I just need to prevent them from being added to the `EventList` if they are already on the `PermanentList`, and a way to switch them.

Comment: `PermanentList` and `EventList` aren't related to anything?

Comment: @IainShelvington Nope. They are the objects. It's a record keeping app, that's it.

Comment: @alias51 Okay, but what are `PermanentList` and `EventList` related to, the same model?? What additional fields are required for each "List"?

Comment: @IainShelvington, Sorry I think I have phrased the question badly. Imaging they are instead `CarList` and `BusList`, with `Drivers`. Does this make sense?

Comment: Lets say that `employee 1` is in `event_list 1` and in `event_list 2`.  If he gets added to `permanent_list 3`, does this mean he can't be in `event_list 3`?  or does it mean he can't be in `event_list 1, 2, 3`?

Comment: @ReinstateMonica there is a `UniqueConstraint` so `employee` can only be in the `EventList` once. I need a way to prevent Employees being in both `EventList` and `PermanentList` at the model level, and then a manual function to change the status from one to the other.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC:

```
class EventMembership(models.Model):
    ...

    def clean(self):
        if PermanentMembership.objects.filter(
                permanent_employees__id=self.event_employees.id
            ).exists():
            raise ValidationError("Employee in PermanentList")
```

As for the second question, you could create an insert signal on `PermanentMembership` that checks if the employee is in `EventMembership`, and if it is, then delete it:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class PermanentMembership(models.Model):
    ...

@reciever(post_save, sender=PermanentMembership)
def handler(sender, **kwargs):
    try:
        event_employee = EventMembership.objects.get(id=sender.id)
        event_employee.delete()
    except EventMembership.DoesNotExist:
        pass
```

Unfortunately, this will hinder performance a bit, since you will have to query the `PermanentMembership` each time you insert on `EventMembership`.  To circumvent this I would cache a list of employee ids that are in `PermanentMembership`, and update that list after each insert.

That being said, I would encourage you to reconsider your database design, because something seems out of place (with the limited info I have on the situation, at least).  I could be completely wrong though, it really depends on the details.

Comment: Also, you should remove the `s` in the `Employees` model, because plural table names are confusing :-P

Comment: Thanks this is really helpful. I haven't come across Cache before and can't find it in the docs. Could you link me to what you are referring to please?

Comment: also would you know how to take your `ValidationError` and write it as a `Q` function so I could enforce a `CheckConstraint` at the model level for improved integrity?

Comment: Here is the [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/cache/) for Django's cache.  It is fairly straightforward to use once you have it configured.  I'd recommend using redis for learning because it is easy to implement.

Comment: @alias51 As for the second question, I'm not sure how to use a constraint with your current database design, because `PermanentMembership` and `EventMembership` aren't connected by a foreign key.  If it is possible to have a constraint like this, it would be fairly complex SQL code that *might* not be possible using Django's ORM alone (although I'm not sure).

Answer (score 0):

Take this potential model layout for example, each `Employee` can only be assigned to 1 `Job` and can only be either `PERMANENT` or `EVENT`. What's wrong with having this layout?

```
from django.db import models

PERMANENT = 'PERMANENT'
EVENT = 'EVENT'


class Job(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    @property
    def permanent_list(self):
        return self.employees.filter(type=PERMANENT)

    @property
    def event_list(self):
        return self.employees.filter(type=EVENT)


class Employee(models.Model):

    EMPLOYMENT_TYPES = (
        (PERMANENT, 'Permanent'),
        (EVENT, 'Event'),
    )

    email = models.EmailField()
    job = models.ForeignKey(Job, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='employees')
    type = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=EMPLOYMENT_TYPES)
```